# Is there a USB ethernet (wired) adapter that is really compatible with Windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: windows-7, usb, 64-bit, ethernet

I've checked the Windows 7 compatibility site, and it lists a fair few USB ethernet (wired, not wireless) adapters that *should* work with Windows 7 64-bit. However, whenever I Google for the model number and Windows 7 64-bit, there's many forum posts claiming that the devices actually don't work with 64-bit (but do work with 32-bit). I've actually also found this with the LUPO USB ethernet adapter; works with 32-bit win7, but not 64-bit (no drivers available).

So is there anyone out there who is **100% certain**, and have actually used successfully, a 64-bit win7 capable USB ethernet adapter?

Comment: The Trendnet TU2-ET100 is a good hit according to: http://www.sevenforums.com/hardware-devices/85761-looking-usb-ethernet-adapter-win7-64-bit.html

Comment: ... looks promising. The driver download has a Vista_64 dir, and as 32-bit vista drivers sometimes work on 32-bit win7, I could draw the conclusion that 64-bit vista drivers work on 64-bit win7 -- so I think I'll risk it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of research and a bit of luck, I can confirm that the following works on Windows 7 64-bit...

- [TRENDNET TU2-ET 10010/100 MBPS USB TO ETHERNET ADAPTER](http://www.pixmania.co.uk/uk/uk/1805385/art/trendnet/tu2-et-10010-100-mbps-usb.html?srcid=867)

... or anything with the [AX88772](http://www.asix.com.tw/products.php?op=pItemdetail&PItemID=86;71;101) chip (as there is a Windows 7 64-bit Driver).

Comment: Got my +1, guess this info will come handy. :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm a bit uneasy about recommending Pixmania, as they're a bit slow (and expensive) for delivery (2-3 day delivery -- ordered on Thursday, but came on Wednesday the following week). So if anyone knows of a better supplier, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

http://accessories.ap.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=au&l=en&s=dhs&cs=audhs1&sku=750-31067&baynote_bnrank=0&baynote_irrank=0&~ck=baynoteSearch

I have the Dell XPS 13 which runs on Win 7 64 bit system.

This was recommended to me as compatible for my XPS.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.